# How to capture video of running Automation scripts on android device?

Tags: android

I want to record/take videos of running automation scripts on android device for demo purpose.

currently I am using adb to record my scripts as

> adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/example.mp4

But problem with this is i am not able to record more than 2.5 to 3 minutes, I have around 4-5 minutes of running scripts for an end to end scenario.Also it saves video on Mobile device only.

Is there is any other utility/program from which i can record my full length automation execution?

Need your thoughts / inputs for the same.

Thanks